# How to deactivate redirect for non-logged in users on specific pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, redirect

I created a website wide (wordpress) redirect for non-logged in users by adding the following code to my function.php file:

```
 function admin_redirect() {
   if ( !is_user_logged_in()) {
       wp_redirect( home_url('/login') );
       exit;
   }
}
add_action('get_header', 'admin_redirect');
```

However there are a few pages, which should be accessible for non-logged in users. Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check conditionally tags in your funciton 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

```
function admin_redirect() {
   if( is_page('about_us') )
   return;

   if ( !is_user_logged_in()) {
       wp_redirect( home_url('/login') );
       exit;
   }
}
```